# I'd like to search a file, find matching terms from another list and then mark rows including those terms

Tags: python, csv

having a bit of a mental block today so I need a little help.

I have a large file showing interactions between gene pairs, it looks like so:

```
GeneA   GeneB   0.8475
GeneA   GeneC   0.9865
GeneB   GeneA   0.9865
GeneD   GeneB   0.5174
```

and so on...

I also have another file, listing some genes which I'm interested in, like so:

```
GeneD
GeneC
```

essentially, I'd like a short script which iterates over the first file, finds cases where a gene in the second file is present in the row, and simply append an asterisk to that row so I can easily spot these interactions later.

To complete my example, given these two files, I'd like to alter my first file like so:

```
GeneA   GeneB   0.8475
GeneA   GeneC   0.9865 *
GeneB   GeneA   0.9865
GeneD   GeneB   0.5174 *
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: there is useful article here about how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask one point there recommends that you should do some research and document how you tried to solve problem you encounter. Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? If yes what have you tried? If not, what stops you from doing this? Lots of useful information about good practices is also in this discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat data
GeneA   GeneB   0.8475
GeneA   GeneC   0.9865
GeneB   GeneA   0.9865
GeneD   GeneB   0.5174
$ cat data1 
GeneD
GeneC
$ python3 p.py 
$ cat output 
GeneA   GeneB   0.8475
GeneA   GeneC   0.9865  *
GeneB   GeneA   0.9865
GeneD   GeneB   0.5174  *
$
```

Here is the python script:

```
genes=[]
with open('data1', 'r') as f:
    genes=set(map(lambda line:line.strip(), f.readlines()))

with open('output', 'w') as f:
    with open('data', 'r') as csvfile:
        for i in map(lambda line:line.strip(), csvfile.readlines()):
            print(i+"\t*" if set(i.split()[0:2]) & genes else i, file=f)
            #print >>f, i+"\t*" if set(i.split()[0:2]) & genes else i   #for Python 2.x
```